# Change Marker to Blue Dot in Android Google Maps v2 using Google Maps v3

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I have used the Android Google Maps v2 and one feature that I like about it is the blue dot that tracks your location on the map. The blue dot changes to an arrow if you start moving which is also great. However, what I have achieved on Google Maps JS api v3 is I can put marker on my location using geolocation. Is there a way to put the blue dot and the blue arrow from google maps v2?

Thanks! :)

EDIT:

```
var map;
var marker;
function initialize() {
var mapOptions = {
zoom: 18
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
  mapOptions);

 // Try HTML5 geolocation
if(navigator.geolocation) {
  mapAutoUpdate();
} else {
// Browser doesn't support Geolocation
handleNoGeolocation(false);
}
}

function mapAutoUpdate(){
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                     position.coords.longitude);

    var shellCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(14.635595,121.033074);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map:map,
        draggable:true,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        position: pos
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', toggleBounce);


      var shellMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: shellCenter
        });
      var shellCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
          map: map,
          strokeColor: '#FF0000',
          strokeOpacity: 0.8,
          strokeWeight: 2,
          center: shellCenter
      });

      shellCircle.setRadius(40);

      var result = distance( marker.getPosition().lat(), marker.getPosition().lng(), shellMarker.getPosition().lat(), shellMarker.getPosition().lng());
    if(result<shellCircle.getRadius()){

        alert("inside!");
    }

    else 
        alert("outside!");

    map.setCenter(pos);
  }, function() {
    handleNoGeolocation(true);
  });
  setTimeout(mapAutoUpdate, 5000);
}



function distance(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) {
var R = 6378137; // km (change this constant to get miles)
var dLat = (lat2-lat1) * Math.PI / 180;
var dLon = (lon2-lon1) * Math.PI / 180; 
var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.cos(lat1 * Math.PI / 180 ) * Math.cos(lat2 * Math.PI / 180 ) * 
    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2); 
var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
var d = R * c;
return d;
 }

function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
 if (errorFlag) {
 var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
 } else {
var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
}

 var options = {
map: map,
position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
content: content
};

 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
 map.setCenter(options.position);
}

function toggleBounce() {

  if (marker.getAnimation() != null) {
    marker.setAnimation(null);
  } else {
    marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
  }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Hi Miguel, would you mind pasting some code ?

Answer (score 0):

You might try using the [Geolocation Marker](https://chadkillingsworth.github.io/geolocation-marker/) from the [Google Maps Utility Library](http://googlemaps.github.io/libraries.html). It doesn't have the arrow, but it has the other functionality you want.